# Advantages of using nServiceBus SendOnly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nservicebus

I'm using an ASP.NET MVC application to send messages to an nServiceBus host on another machines. I'm using

```
Bus.CreateSendOnly(busConfiguration);
```

over

```
Bus.Create(busConfiguration);
```

since the `SendOnly` configuration seems closer to the functionality I'm expecting.

Are there any advantages to making this change besides slightly improved code readability? Does nServiceBus dependency injection behaviour differ, improve performance etc??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CreateSendOnly` bypasses all the processes associated with establishing, verifying and monitoring an input queue to the current process.  Depending on your transport layer this may or may not be significant.

It is recommended in a process that doesn't actually handle any commands or subscribe to any events, both because those overheads are unnecessary, and as you say, it enhances clarity of intent.

A typical process that would have a Send Only bus is a web app or api that is receiving requests and converting them to commands to be processed by endpoint services - sending the commands in a 'fire and forget' mode where it doesn't care about the outcome.

Comment: Note that if you do care about the outcome at the client, you will need to make the web app a normal bus, so it gets an input queue and can receive the reply message, OR (and I personally recommend this) leave it as SendOnly, and find another way to get the outcome back to the client - either have the client poll, or have another dedicated endpoint mediating between bus messages and a websocket or signalr notification pathway to the client.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you for your time Chris. (I actually checked your profile to see if you worked for Particular Software..)